# Usar o Count para retornar case when com ID selecionados

Tags: mysql, case, when

Quero que o SQL me retorne 4 colunas:

ID usuario - OK

Nome do Vendedor - OK

Contagem de ID Contrato em um período especifico (condição de tempo já inserida no where) - OK

Contagem de IDMotivoCancelamento de cada vendedor sendo que preciso inserir uma condição dos IDs (Nem todos são considerados) e também da data do cancelamento. - NÃO OK

Como ajustar?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CT.IDUsuario
,USR.NomeUsuario as Vendedor_Contrato
,CT.DataCancelamentoContrato
,COUNT(DISTINCT CT.IDContrato) as Ativacao_150D
,CT.IDMotivoCancelamento as Cancelamento_Mes

CASE WHEN 
(CT.IDMotivoCancelamento in 88,100
AND CT.DataCancelamentoContrato BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-03-24'
THEN COUNT(CT.IDMotivoCancelamento) END AS CHURN


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLVgM.png
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Experimente colocar o Case dentro do Count:

```
COUNT(
    CASE 
        WHEN CT.IDMotivoCancelamento in (88, 100) AND
             CT.DataCancelamentoContrato BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-03-24'
            THEN CT.IDMotivoCancelamento
    END) AS CHURN
```

Answer (score -4):

Boa noite! Tudo bem? Espero que sim.

Pelo que entendi, a condição que você precisa é que sejam os ids 88 e 100 e que esteja entre 1 e 24 de março, correto? Para este resultado, você precisa usar especificamente o CASE WHEN? Se você não precisar usar necessariamente o CASE WHEN, Tente trocar o CASE WHEN por WHERE, desta forma:

`Where CT.IDMotivoCancelamento in (88, 100) and CT.DataCancelamentoContrato BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-03-24'`

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).